# A (highfalutin) word for a highfalutin word?

Tags: vocabulary

> To illustrate the question, badroit used the word "meretricious" meretriciously.

Is there an English word that describes highfalutin words like "meretricious" that are (gratuitously) used in place of better-understood words like "garish"?

The word may or may not be self-describing.

Comment: If *meretricious* is used to mean *garish* the technical term is *error*.

Comment: Mmm, *sequipedalian*?

Comment: *Sequipedalian* is very good. It's not so much about the length of the word though as its obscurity, but it seems *sequipedalian* probably fits both connotations.

Comment: @StoneyB, I wasn't suggesting that *meretricious* and *garish* are equivalent, but that they could be used in this context equivalently. Why *error*?

Comment: Because they don't mean the same thing. The art of Bouguereau is not at all garish, but it is highly meretricious.

Comment: Maybe [Inspector Grim](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0nOKTDevJA&feature=youtu.be&t=5m55s) can help you with a few synonyms

Comment: @tchrist:  Do you mean sesquipedalian? (with an S before the Q)

Comment: @rhetorician Certainly, as in [*sesquipedalia verba* from Horace](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-ses1.htm).

Comment: *Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian* also seems worthy of mention, even though its status as a word is questionable.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate of the linked question. This question seeks a word for a word. The other question seeks a word for a person.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Sesquipedalian* literally means 'a foot and a half long', and was originally applied to unnecessarily long words (in Latin); it has expanded in English to include people who use such words.

Comment: [Here’s](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-ses1.htm) a nice link.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to TimLymington's excellent *sesquipedalian*, you might consider also *grandiloquent*.  Its meaning tends more towards *bombastic*, so use just a dash if it fits your recipe.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you seek adjectives.

*[Ostentatious](http://www.memidex.com/ostentatious)* fits the bill:

> ostentatious
>
> adjective
>
> 1. (dicty) intended to attract notice and impress others
>
>    Synonyms: pretentious, dicty [slang, United States]. Similar to: flamboyant, flaunty
> 2. (tasteless) of a display, tawdry or vulgar
>
>    Synonyms: pretentious. Similar to: tasteless

Depending on the nature of the situation, you might consider *[flamboyant](http://www.memidex.com/flamboyant)* ("elaborate or excessively ornamented") or *[pretentious](http://www.memidex.com/pretentious)* ("making claim to or creating an appearance of (often undeserved) importance or distinction").

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking for a word to describe the word itself or its use. For example, sequipedalian suggested by @tchrist is quite good since it describes the character of the word itself.

Comment: @badroit True. *Ostentatious* describes less the nature of *the word* and more the nature of *its use*.

Answer (score 2):

*Bombast* / *bombastic* will suit your requirements.

*[Bombast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bombast)*: *pretentious inflated speech or writing*